# Which one to use in function annotations: list or List[]

Tags: python, function, annotations

Here and there, I see people using annotations in two somehow different ways:

```
# 1:
def calcul(numbers: list) -> int:
    pass


# 2:
from typing import List
def calcul(numbers: List[int]) -> int:
    pass
```

The question is what is the difference and/or which one is more preferable?

Answer (score 0):

`calcul(numbers: List[int])` will give you a warning if the list you are sending to the function doesn't contain `int` (you can still run the code without errors)

```
calcul(['asd'])
```

> Expected type 'List[int]', got 'List[str]' instead

```
calcul(['asd', 1])
```

However will not produce the warning.